# Continous action-state-space and tiling

Tags: algorithm, reinforcement-learning

After getting used to the `Q-Learning` algorithm in discrete action-state-space I would like to expand this now to continous spaces. To do this I read the chapter `On-Policy Control with Approximation` of Sutton´s introduction. Here, the usage of differentiable functions like a linear function or an `ANN` are recommended to solve the problem of continous action-state-space. Nevertheless Sutton then discribes the tiling method which maps the continous variables onto a discrete presentation. Is this always necessary?

Trying to understand this methods I tried to implement the example of the `Hill Climbing Car` in the book without the tiling method and a linear base function `q`. As my state space is 2 dimensional, and my action is one dimensional I used a three dimensional weight vector `w` in this equation:
[image]

When I now try to choose the action which will maximize the output, the obvious answer will be a=1, if w_2 > 0. Therefore, the weight will slowly converge to positive zero and the agent will not learn anything useful. As Sutton is able to solve the problem using the tiling I am wondering if my problem is caused by the absence of the tiling method or if I am doing anything else wrong.
So: Is the tiling always necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your main question about tiling, the answer is no, not always it is necessary using tiling.

As you tried, it's a good idea to implement some easy example as the *Hill Climbing Car* in order to fully understand the concepts. Here, however, you are misundertanding something important. When the book talks about linear methods, it is refering to *linear in the parameters*, which means that you can extract a set of (non linear) features and combine them linearly. This kind of approximators can represent functions much more complex than a standard *linear regression*.

The parametrization you have proposed it's not able to represent a non-linear Q function. Taking into account that in the `Hill Climbing problem` you want to learn Q-functions of this style:

[image]

You will need something more powefull than [image]. An easy solution for your problem could be to use a Radial Basis Function (RBF) network. In this case, you use a set of features (or BF, like for example Gaussians functions) to map your state space:

[image]

Additionally, if your action space is discrete and small, the easiest solution is to maintain an independent RBF network for each action. For selecting the action, simply compute the Q value for each action and select the one with higher value. In this way you avoid the (complex) optimization problem of selecting the best action in a continuous function.

You can find a more detailed explanation on the Busoniu et al. book *Reinforcement Learning and Dynamic Programming Using Function Approximators*, pages 49-51. It's available for free [here](https://orbi.ulg.ac.be/bitstream/2268/27963/1/book-FA-RL-DP.pdf).

Comment: Okay. But I think Sutton has been using just the linear features created by the tiling-algorithm - or is this already calculating non-linear terms?

Comment: In the case of tile-coding, it's true that the features are extremely simple. They are binary features that can only take two values (0 or 1), in fact they are more simple than linear features. However, there exists several exhaustive partitions of the input space, which makes tile coding method much more powerful than the linear model `w_0 * s_0 + w_1 * s_1`.